# How to remove the transparent effect (i.e. some portion of the object is seen through) when it is rotated?

Tags: 3d-view

I am starting off using Blender. When I imported .obj file into blender and rotated the model, some portions are seen through like transparent view and the cut-through view is varying based on how much I rotate the model. I do want to remove that effect and see the model clearly as looking from outside.[image]

Comment: This could be an insufficient clipping range to contain your object: https://imgur.com/a/d7DfslA

Comment: As @RobinBetts says, this is due to the set clipping range. Another indicator that it's not a problem with the model is the grid floor disappearing as well. In your case the _Clip Start_ value is too high, because everything closer and the grid in the foreground is not visible. If the _Clip End_ value was too low, the grid in the background would disappear.